# Get all files with infos(name, type, size) within directory node-fs

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a ***route*** to a location where I want to make a read

```
var route = ('F:\\uploads\\ponys');
```

with `var rez = fs.readdirSync(route, 'utf8');` it return an Array of all files(and folders) inside of the route.

```
console.log(rez);
[ 'file.rtf',
  'Course.rtf',
  'extra.png',
  'ar102.rar',
  'New folder']
```

I want to return an JSON Object which contains name, type and size. How I can proceed to obtain this:

```
{
  "files":[
    {"name": "file", "type": "rtf", "size": 3445},  [or with "."(.rtf)]
    {"name": "Course", "type": "rtf", "size": 900},
    {"name": "extra", "type": "png", "size": 2424},
    {"name": "ar102", "type": "rar", "size": 340432},
    {"name": "New folder", "type": "", "size": 123456789} 
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is npm module please check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree)

Comment: It works great but I need to find a solution for figure out what extension the file have. If it is a file or folder.(a clean .txt have 0 byte like a folder, a folder can be named "asd.pony")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For each file in a dir, you're trying to get 3 values:

1. **file name**: already got it with `readdirSync`)
2. **file extension**: use `path.extname(filename)`
3. **file size**: use `fs.statSync(filename).size`

#### 1. Getting file extension example

```
const path = require('path');
const extension = path.extname('index.html');
// 'html'
```

#### 2. Getting file size example

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync('file.html').size;
```

#### 3. Complete approach

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const getFileInfoFromFolder = (route) => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(route, 'utf8');
  const response = [];
  for (let file of files) {
    const extension = path.extname(file);
    const fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync(route + file).size;
    response.push({ name: file, extension, fileSizeInBytes });
  }
  return response;
}

const { name, extension, fileSizeInBytes } = getFileInfoFromFolder("...")
```

Comment: I got an error **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\Web\myappfolder\\server\file.rtf'** This path is to node server not to upload folder. I tried to change path to upload path.dirname(route); but the same error appear. **file.rtf** is the first file in the **UPLOAD** folder

Comment: Maybe he want ro determine size and type of the file(file.rtf) in the server location not the upload folder location.

Comment: Have you check the route? (seems there is an extra \ around there) anyway, this is a workaround for getting info for a file list, seems you are now having troubles with the paths.

Comment: If I remove `let fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync(file).size;` and also from response it's work flawless. With statSync enabled the same error appear **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\Web\myappfolder\server\file.rtf'** F:\Web\myappfolder\server is server path and file.rtf is first file in upload folder(Why he search in server path idn) Thanks for your time

Comment: my process.cwd()(just before statSync call)  is on F:\Web\myappfolder\server not the upload folder this may be the problem ?

Comment: even the fileSizeInBytes is working fine, all you have do is write this line there `const fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync(path.join(route, file)).size;`

Comment: As @KNDheeraj already mentioned you should add the base directory to `fs.statSync` otherwise it will look for only filename

Comment: You must add the route to stat like this: const fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync(route + file).size;