# Node.js get all files in directory with 0 bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory with hundreds of thousands of files, some of them have 0 bytes because of connection errors, I would like to download them again. How do I get their filenames based on their size?

Comment: Do you need this to be recursive?

Comment: @raina77ow no, flat dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `fs.promises` is an option, the code might be quite concise. This version has small additional feature: it excludes directories, by supplying readdir with `withFileTypes` function then checking `isFile()` on those [Dirent](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

(async() => {
  const fileEntries = await fs.readdir(__dirname, { 
    encoding: 'utf8', 
    withFileTypes: true 
  });
  const zeroSizeFiles = await Promise.all( 
    fileEntries.filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
      .map(async ({ name }) => (await fs.stat(name)).size ? null : name)
    );

  console.log(zeroSizeFiles.filter(Boolean));
})()
```

If this check is not required (no subdirectories), it's even more concise:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

(async () => {
  const filenames = await fs.readdir(__dirname);
  const zeroSizeFiles = await Promise.all( 
    filenames.map(async name => (await fs.stat(name)).size ? null : name)
  );
  console.log(zeroSizeFiles.filter(Boolean));
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here: [Get all files with infos(name, type, size) within directory node-fs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539064/get-all-files-with-infosname-type-size-within-directory-node-fs)

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const getFileInfoFromFolder = (route) => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(route, 'utf8');
  const response = [];
  for (let file of files) {
    const extension = path.extname(file);
    const fileSizeInBytes = fs.statSync(file).size;
    if (fileSizeInBytes == 0) {
      response.push(file);
    }
  }
  return response;
}

const zero_size_files = getFileInfoFromFolder("...")
```

Comment: This works if you replace the file with route+file during statSync.

Answer (score 1):

What about if we use the command line list all empty files from a folder??

```
find ./ -name '*.txt' -size 0
```

I believe this is a fastest ways if possible :D

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec("find ./ -name '*.txt' -size 0", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
       // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
    }

    // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Yes if you want it to work only on a single OS

Comment: ^^ We have 3 type of OS (IOS absolutely this is not a server OS, Window Server and Linux ^^) just use a condition and convert the command line, I think it is better performance than load all files and check the file size.